# Как сделать простенький preloader?

Tags: javascript, html, css

использовал js код и селекторы, которые задают стиль для самого лоадера.

```
function onLoad(){
    setTimeout(function onLoad(){
        var preloader = document.getElementById('page-pre');
            if( !preloader.classList.contains('done'))
            {
            preloader.classList.add('done');
            }
    }, 100);
    }
```

Но что-то пошло не так и сам прелоадер не работает. В чём ошибка не могу понять, может кто подкинет вариант попроще?

Comment: если не хотите париться используйте pace.js https://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо, но там всё сложновато для меня. Хотелось бы понимать, как это всё работает))
пока начну с чего-нибудь попроще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так. Если что, то сам уже сумеешь, я думаю, подстроить под себя .loader.

https://jsfiddle.net/Fyuuri/c3t7m2qf/77/ Песочница для удобства.

```js
var page_preloader = document.getElementById("page");
setTimeout(function() {
  page_preloader.style.display = "none";

}, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background: whitesmoke;
}
.block{
  padding:20px;
 width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-bottom-color: green;
  border-left-color: red;
  border-right-color:  yellow;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 0;
  }
.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
}

.loader-line1 {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  animation: 2s spin infinite;
  z-index: 2;
}

.loader-line2 {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  animation: 3s spin infinite;
  z-index: 1;
}

.loader-line3 {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  animation: 3s spin infinite;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
```

```html
<div id="page" class="preloader">
  <div class="loader-line1">

    <div class="loader-line2">

      <div class="loader-line3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block">


  <h1 align="center">
    <span lang="ru"><font size="5">Заголовок.</font></span></h1>
  <p align="center"><span lang="ru"><font size="5">Текст блока.</font></span></div>
<p>

  </div>
```

```
var page_preloader = document.getElementById("page");
setTimeout(function() {
  page_preloader.style.display = "none";

}, 2000);
```